# An upper bound for $\log \operatorname{rad}(n!)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $n>1$ be an integer and let $\operatorname{rad}(n!)$ denote the radical of $n$-factorial. (The radical of an integer $m$ being, loosely speaking, the product of the prime divisors of $m$.)

Can one give an upper bound for $\log \operatorname{rad}(n!)$ better than $n\log n$?

**Proof:** $$ \log \operatorname{rad}(n!) \leq \log (n!) \leq \log (n^n) \leq n \log n. $$

Comment: Why "loosely speaking"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\text{rad}(n!)$ is just the product of the primes less than or equal to $n$ (so a [primorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)), so

$$\log \text{ rad}(n!) = \mathop{\sum_{p \le n\;|\;p \text{ prime}}} \log p$$

also known as the first [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\vartheta(n)$. The statement that $\vartheta(n) \sim n$ is equivalent to the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), and the [Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) gives bounds on the error of this approximation. More information is available at the Wikipedia article and in most books on analytic number theory.

[Erdős' proof of Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate#Lemma_4:_An_upper_bound_on_the_primorial) includes as a lemma the elementary upper bound

$$\vartheta(n) \le n \log 4.$$

Comment: Nice! This is much better than $n\log n$ to me.

Answer (score 6):

A short proof:  Notice that all the primes $p$ with $n<p\leq 2n$ must divide $\binom{2n}{n}$ so that $\frac{\text{rad}((2n)!)}{\text{rad}(n!)}\leq \binom{2n}{n}$.  Also, $\binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^n$.  Consequently for $n=2^k$

$$\text{rad}(n!)\leq \binom{n}{n/2}\cdot \binom{n/2}{n/4}\cdots \binom{2}{1}\leq 4^\frac{n}{2} \cdot 4^\frac{n}{4}\cdots 2\leq 4^n$$

and we see $\log \text{rad}(n!)\leq n\log 4$ for $n=2^k$.  You can get other $n$ by noticing $\log \text{rad}(n!)$ is monotonic.  (Without cleverness you could lose a factor of $2$ at worst)