# non-trivial upper bound for the number of primes less or equal to n

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Using a result of Erdos as in this question

[An upper bound for $\log \operatorname{rad}(n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52895/an-upper-bound-for-log-radn)

one can show that

$\sum_{p\leq n} \log p \leq \log(4) n$ for any positive integer $n$.

Trivially, $\sum_{p\leq n} 1 \leq n$.

Are there any other non-trivial upper bounds for $\sum_{p\leq n} 1$?

Note that I'm asking for upper bounds and not just asymptotic behaviour. Moreover, this is probably connected to the prime number theorem.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28540

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many proofs of the prime number theorem involve some bounds. I'm familiar with a result of Pierre Dusart, stating that for all x, $\pi(x) \leq \frac{x}{\log x}(1 + \frac{1.2762}{\log x})$.

He was actually more proud of his lower bound. His paper is [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/home.html).

Comment: Better: http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442

Answer (score 3):

See [Explicit bounds for some functions of prime numbers](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371291) by Rosser (1941, [MR0003018](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3018)). Among other results, there is
$$\frac x{\log x+2} < \pi(x) < \frac x{\log x-4},\quad\mbox{for } x\geq 55$$

Similar explicit bounds can be found in [Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) by Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962, [MR0137689](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=137689)).

For a sample of recent work, see [Short effective intervals containing primes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-314X%2802%2900029-X) by Ramaré and Saouter (2004, [MR1950435](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1950435)).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/is-p-n-pin-4n-where-p-n-is-the-largest-prime-leq-n

Comment: Thanks for posting that link to Rosser's paper. I have a copy from when I was a math undergraduate, but it's nice to have an electronic copy. It's a little dated (done in 1961, refers to computations done on an IBM 650, ...), so I wonder what has been done in the last 50 years.

Comment: @marty: I have converted your answer to a comment on lhf's post. Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Comment: @marty, I've added a link to some recent work.

Comment: Also take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59258/lower-bound-for-the-prime-number-function

Answer (score 2):

Your sum is just $\pi(n)$, the number of primes less than or equal to $n$.  This is the subject of the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)