# lower bound for the prime number function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does there exist a function $f$ that is a lower bound of the prime number function $\pi$ with $f \sim \pi$?

Comment: Just to be a little puckish, I will note that $$f(x)=\pi(x)-1$$ 
satisfies your requirements :)

Comment: Yep, thanks. My wording should be more precise...

Comment: $pi(x)$ is the prime number counting function, not the prime number function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a more 'elegant' lower bound:

$$ \frac{n}{\log\,n} - 2 \leq \pi(n), \; n \geq 2 $$ [Primality Testing in Polynomial Time](https://doi.org/10.1007/b12334)

Comment: There is a proof on page 46: http://www.springerlink.com/content/p9rft7x5nkbwjkq6/

Comment: Sorry, was thinking of $\text{li}(x)$, that bounces back and forth from below $\pi(x)$ to above.

Comment: Although, I am not sure what is meant by $\log$ in the paper. The author distinguishes between $\ln$ (natural logarithm) and $\log$ (base 2 or base 10, maybe?)...

Comment: On second or third thought, I am again very surprised at the result, and doubtful. Maybe there is confusion with estimates of $p_n$. I do not trust Wolfram Mathworld assertions, they are often wrong.

Comment: mmh, I don't think so, Martin Dietzfelbinger seems like a reliable source.

Answer (score 10):

[This segment of the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) mentions a few such bounds. In all cases, the bounds hold from a certain explicit $N$ on.  They can be easily be made unconditional without 
changing the asymptotic behaviour by  suitably redefining the functions for $x \lt N$.

For instance, the article mentions the bounds
$$\frac{x}{\ln x+2}<\pi(x)<\frac{x}{\ln x-4},$$
valid for $x \ge 55$, as well as much stronger bounds by Pierre Dusart.  Since $\pi(x)$ is asymptotically $x/\ln x$, the two bounds above have the right asymptotic properties. Tweaking the lower bound so that it is valid below $55$ is easy.  The crudest method  is to use the function which is $-1$ for $x \lt 55$, and $x/(\ln x +2)$ for $x \ge 55$.  Asymptotic behaviour is unaffected.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54312/non-trivial-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-primes-less-or-equal-to-n/54325#54325.

Comment: I wanted to add the [article](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf) of Dussart.

Comment: @mixedmath: Thanks for the helpful addition.