# Euclidean and induction with prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have been given the following question in my homework:

> Show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are at least ${\log_2log_2 (n-1)}$ primes in $[1,n]$

I think it is related to euclidean and induction but I am having difficulties developing my solution.

Thanks for your help (:

Answer (score 1):

Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes also shows that the $n$-th prime satisfies $p_n\le 2^{2^{n}}$, which also gives $\pi(n)\ge \log_2(\log_2(n-1))$ , see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65630/how-to-show-p-n-leq-22n).

Remark: We can easily prove a better estimate, using an elementary argument starting with $2^n\le \binom{2n}{n}<4^n$, which gives
$$
\pi(n)>\frac{n}{6\log n}
$$
for all $n\ge 2$ (see also [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59258/lower-bound-for-the-prime-number-function)).