# Is $n=13$ the only solution to this: $\pi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\pi(i)\right)-1=n$.

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I was messing around with the prime counting function $\pi(n)$ because I was bored, but then I noticed something.

> > The equation 
> >     $$\pi\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\pi(i)\right)-1=n,$$ 
> >     has the solution $n=13$. Are there any numbers like $13$ that satisfy this equation? Is there a way of finding like values? Has this been discovered before?

If it can be proven that $13$ is the only number (let alone *prime*) with this property, I will feel like Ulam after discovering upon the famous prime spiral. It is otherwise my conjecture as I am unaware of anyone else finding out this property.

Comment: Other solutions are $n=14, 15$

Comment: @gammatester and that's why I should always test some more myself. I was just bored and a bit lazy today... Is it known whether or not there are infinitely many numbers like this?

Comment: I do not believe so. The function is roughly monotone increasing (with a few exceptions). I guess the [bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) for $\pi(n)$ can be used to disprove your conjecture.

Comment: I believe (if I understand well your formula, I don't know why is tagged with the tag (pi)) that is better write your formula/equation/condition as $\pi\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\pi(k)\right)=n+1$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function. I add also as companion of previous comments a line code written in Pari-GP (search in Internet *Sage Cell Server* and choose *GP* as language) `for (i = 1, 1000,if(primepi(sum( k=1, i, primepi(k)))==i+1,print(i)))`

Comment: "*If $\ldots$ then $n=13$ satisfies*." Could you fix the syntax because this makes no sense right now. On the left is a number, on the right is a set. @gammatester what did you understand of this?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I use the set notation because I have a "such that" in the equation, and thus allows various values of $n$. This is actually very common notation. I will change the syntax though.

Comment: @arnaud-mortier: I considered the zeros of the function
$$f(n) = \pi\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n \pi(i)\Big)-n-1$$

Comment: @user243301 yes you have understood it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that I mean is the same thing that Arnaud. My emphasis, like that of other users, is to be able to write your nice question, the title and the body rigorously.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks. (at)user477343 No, this is not a common notation. A number and a set are two different things unless you are in pure logic which is not the case here, and you do not define a function inside a set.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I was taught to use this notation from a maths book. I forgot what it's called but it was written by a famous author and talked about functions, sets, probability, limits, and some trig and other parts of calculus, also radicals. I guess that's every maths book... but yeah. I thought this was normal notation.

Comment: @Servaes thank you for the edit! My phone died before I could edit it, hahah. It's charging now so all good :)

Comment: The LHS grows as $\left(\frac{n}{\ln{n}}\right)^2$, so faster than $n$. So find some lower bounds for $\pi(k)$ and use them to find an upper bound on $n$ for which the equality could hold; probably you'll find some $n<100$. Then it is a matter of checking these few cases by hand or computer.

Comment: Checked by computer, there are no other solutions except $n=13, 14, 15$, all the way up to $n=10^4$. And the value of the expression on the left side grows faster than $n$. There are no other solutions.

Comment: @Oldboy thank you very much. I went to the following links and they helped: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890741/what-is-the-simplest-lower-bound-on-prime-counting-functions-proof-wise/1890792 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59258/lower-bound-for-the-prime-number-function